# iOS - Setting UIButton background color only colors the corners

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicolor, cgcolor

I'm trying to customize my button by changing their colors, but when I use either:

```
self.loginButton.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:157.0/255.0 blue:223.0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
```

or

```
self.loginButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:157.0/255.0 blue:223.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

All I get is this result:

[image]

What I want to do is change the white color to blue, any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You're using a round rect button which is pretty ugly, and pretty hard to customise.

You can create a custom type button and use a background image, or create a custom type button and round the corners and set the background colour of the layer yourself.

If you want to get really fancy there is a nice tutorial [here](http://undefinedvalue.com/2010/02/27/shiny-iphone-buttons-without-photoshop) which can give you any-sized gradient type buttons using layers, no image files required.

Comment: Thank you very much :) is there by any chance anything more recent? Or is this still the way it has to be done?

Comment: Would be nice to have something more current, that's why I ask, sorry for the trouble

Comment: The link is still relevant advice. The built in buttons in iOS are pretty poor once you move out of bar button items or action sheets.

Comment: Those buttons from tutorial don't seem to work, when you initialize button using class method UIButton buttonWithType.

Answer (score 2):

What's that button type? If you want to customise button, you gotta create a button with [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]

Comment: Yes. This is very important and easy to miss. I don't know how many times I have spend half an hour trying to figure out why my buttons didn't look right before finally realizing that I didn't have them set to Custom.

Answer (score -2):

I discovered this almost by accident:

```
self.loginButton.tintColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

Definitely works and has been available since iOS 2.0.

Comment: The tintColor only sets the color when the button is pressed down.