# Fill the UIButton with a color when touched up inside

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicolor

I want to fill the UIButton with color when it is touched. The method can be implemented in the action method

```
- (IBAction)bocClick:(UIButton *)sender {
    [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
}
```

i get the button like below

[image]

this background is not enough for my need ,i need have an effect ,something like..

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a round `rect` button which is bit complex to customize.

You can create a custom type button and use a background image, or create a custom type button and round the corners and set the background `colour` of the layer yourself.

or you can also do with bellow:-

you can add UIView or Lable like this bellow example:-

```
- (IBAction)bocClick:(UIButton *)sender {

UILabel *lbl2=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:_btn.bounds];
lbl2.text=@"Button";
lbl2.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentCenter;
lbl2.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
lbl2.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
lbl2.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
lbl2.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[sender addSubview:lbl2];
}
```

OUTPUT IS:-

[image]

something similor:-

[iOS - Setting UIButton background color only colors the corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9979057/ios-setting-uibutton-background-color-only-colors-the-corners)

Comment: does there any way to add a view over the buttton's frame which we can get from the "sender.frame" and place it over the button to make a similar effect...i dont need touch up again so ?

Comment: yes you can add view as a subview ofButton at che TouchUpInside method

Answer (score 1):

You just have to set the `tintColor`property:
`[sender setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];`

So you get the highlight color when TouchUpInside. If you also want to change the background color it's more complex. Then you have to use `Quartz`

Comment: this willn't work i have already tried :(
thanks though

Answer (score 1):

Only do this

UIButton * bocClick = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

Answer (score 1):

please try changing the button Type to UiButtonTypeCustom.
Please look at the image below.
[image]
hope it will help you.